# Sharing internet between two computers over telephone line

Tags: networking, internet, connection

I have an old Windows 98 era computer that I would like to hook up to my home network/internet. Only problem is, it only has a modem, no ethernet. I have another computer that has ethernet and a modem. Is there any way, using a telephone cable, that I could connect the old computer to the network via the other computer?

Comment: Typically modems are connected to the PC via serial connector and those serial ports can be used for a direct connection without the modems. A modem requires a special dial-in counter part so they bill be of no use to you. In my opinion I would not connect a W98 PC to the internet, that is pretty dangerous and e.g. https web sites will not work as the system is way too old.

Comment: I highly recommend looking into adding a 'pci fast ethernet' most computers with win98 would support that. Modems were painfully slow 20 years ago and filesizes have increased. Modems would require a dailup and although you could answer mode calls you'd need two analogue phone lines. Some voipboxes would have 2 pots/pstn lines but sounds like far more complicated than adding a network card